# Only remove image elements from string if they're at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say you have HTML in this format (line breaks for ease of reading):

```
var html_string = '<p class="text">
  Hello my name is
  <a href="http://example.com">Joe</a>
  and I am an alcoholic
  <img class="emoji" src="http://example.com/beer.png">
  <img class="emoji" src="http://example.com/sad.png">
</p>';
```

How would I remove the two emoji images at the end? But only if they are the last elements in the paragraph. If there is text after the emojis then I do not want to remove them. So, for example, they would not be removed in the following:

```
var html_string = '<p class="text">
  Hello my name is
  <a href="http://example.com">Joe</a>
  and I am an alcoholic
  <img class="emoji" src="http://example.com/beer.png">
  <img class="emoji" src="http://example.com/sad.png">
  Thanks!
</p>'
```

The text is variable and the number of emojis may change. There may be ten, or there may be none at all.

I thought of maybe splitting the text into an array and then looping through it to test whether the last elements were images with that class, but it's proving difficult to check whether an element is the last in an array. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Rather than using regular expressions, I'd suggest applying the string of HTML as the `innerHTML` of a created-element (such as a `<div>`), and then removing the `lastChild` of the element *if* it's an element. This could be done instead with regular expressions, but it's likely to be more fragile.

Comment: Interesting question. Waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't render the elements you'll need to parse the text. This is annoying because parsing HTML with RegEx *is* fundamentally a bad idea. It's easy enough to find an opening tag, but the closing tag and all of the nuances are hardly worth the effort.

If you want though you can try this as a basic example:

`(\<img.+>)`

```js
var html_string = `<p class="text">
  Hello my name is
  <a href="http://example.com">Joe</a>
  and I am an alcoholic
  <img class="emoji" src="http://example.com/beer.png">
  <img class="emoji" src="http://example.com/sad.png">
</p>`;

console.log(html_string.replace(/\<img.+>/gi, "")) ;
```

So what's the issue with this code?

The ending tag `>` will match *any* ending tag, even if it's within an attribute of the img tag. To make it better you can always using a self-closing tag with img elements(circa HTML4) `<img />` and then match that instead. Which *will* make it more accurate, but again if for some reason you have the string `/>` within an attribute it will screw things up.

`/\<img.+\/>/gi`

```js
    var html_string = `<p class="text">
      Hello my name is
      <a href="http://example.com">Joe</a>
      and I am an alcoholic
      <img class="emoji" src="http://example.com/beer.png"/>
      <img class="emoji" src="http://example.com/sad.png"/>
    </p>`;

    console.log(html_string.replace(/\<img.+\/>/gi, "")) ;
```

Another solution as pointed out prevoiusly is if you render the elements you can simply grab the last elements, check if they're images, and remove them:

You can use `lastElementChild` and check if it's an image element.

```js
function removeLastImgs(parent) {
  let node;
  while (node = parent.lastElementChild) {
    if (node.tagName === "IMG") node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    else break;
  }
}

removeLastImgs(document.querySelector("div"));
```

```html
<div>
  <span> hi</span>
  <img src="#" width="300" height="300" /><img src="#" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
```

The BEST solution though? Don't pull those elements in the first place, if you can help it.

Comment: While I agree with the approach you've taken, the string of HTML is contained within a variable, it's not an HTML node.